# Split binary number into groups of zeros and ones

Tags: regex, perl

I have a binary number, for example `10000111000011`, and want to split it into groups of consecutive 1s and 0s, `1 0000 111 0000 11`.

I thought that's a great opportunity to use look-arounds: my regex uses a positive look-behind for a digit (which it captures for later backreferencing), then a negative look-ahead for that same digit (using a backreference), so I should get a split whenever a digit is followed by a digit that is not the same.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $bin_string = '10000111000011';
my @groups = split /(?<=(\d))(?!\g1)/, $bin_string;

say "@groups";
```

However, this results in

```
1 1 0000 0 111 1 0000 0 11 1
```

Somehow, the captured digit is inserted at every split. What did go wrong?

Comment: You do not need `split`. Try `@groups=$bin_string=~/1+|0+/g`..

Comment: That's of course more elegant! I still wanted to understand what was happening and if there maybe was a way to salvage the regex.

Comment: You've got your answer, but I'll just add that when I read this, my first thought was "whoa, too complicated."  `perl -pe 's/(0+|1+)/\1 /g' <<< "10000111000011"` does the job, or if you want something more generalized, `perl -pe 's/((.)\2*)/\1 /g'`.

Comment: @ghoti Absolutely. When I asked this, I was pretty convinced that this wasn't the best way to solve my problem, but I wanted to know why I saw what I saw. In the end, the question was more about "why is the capture group repeated" than "how can I split my string".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small fix for your code:

```
my @groups = split /(?<=0(?!0)|1(?!1))/, $bin_string;
```

The problem you experience is that when using `split` captured texts are also output in the resulting array. So, the solution is to get rid of the capturing group.

Since you only have `0` or `1` in your input, it is pretty easy with an alternation and a lookahead making sure the digits get changed.

See [demo](https://ideone.com/V1XksI)

Comment: While all answers address the underlying problem, I've chosen this one as accepted as it's the only actually answering the "why did this happen". The behaviour for `split` with capturing groups is actually [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). Is there a specific reason you chose your parenthesizing over, say, `(?<=0)(?!0)|(?<=1)(?!1)`?

Comment: I chose this grouping because I followed the alternation logic: we split using a look-behind, and inside, we have 2 alternatives: 1) zero that should not be followed with a zero, and 2) one not followed with one. Yes, splitting with a regex pattern having capturing groups is documented for languages where this works (it [does not work in Java](http://ideone.com/LiwxK6)).

Answer (score 1):

Just do matching instead of splitting.

```
(\d)\1*
```

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $bin_string = '10000111000011';
while($bin_string =~ m/((\d)\2*)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/wqXdum)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=0)(?=1)|(?<=1)(?=0)
```

Simply split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/3

The `lookarounds` will find place where there is `0` behind and `1` ahead or `1` behind and `0` ahead.Thus resulting in correct split without consuming anything.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Cool. If you're wondering about DV's (I didn't DV this or any of your other answers) look to see if you've included an explanation of what you have done. Especially if you're demonstrating regex you can take things a bit further and provide a detailed explanation. Newbies coming to SO and seeing these answers will be better off and might actually gain understanding to solutions.

Comment: Just commenting because you asked above :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah an explanation is surely helpful....will try to get rid of my laziness :)